# How to get rid off box around Leaflet zoom control

Tags: css, leaflet

I have added a map and it is displaying this gray border around the zoom control buttons.

```
<div class="class flex-container vertical">
                <section id="maparea"></section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.vertical {flex-direction: column; }

.leaflet-control-container { position: absolute; right: 56px; width:0px; border: 0px}
```

What to I need to add to the CSS to make it disappear?

[image: picture]

Or do I have to edit something in the leaflet.css file?

Comment: it appears to be ```outline```, you can try to set it to null and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: that did not do the trick, unfortunately... (adding it to the leaflet-control-container style)

Comment: Can you add some working code here or more detail code your current code block information is not enough to understand question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it thanks to using the style tab in Firefox Web Dev Tools.
This solution is not clean, and as one can properly see I do not really undestand it all, but it works :) (It does not get rid of the grey border, but it matches it to the zoom controls).

in leaflet.css I put:

```
.leaflet-top .leaflet-control {
    margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-right: 0px; outline: 0px; border:0px}
```

And in my own css file I have:

`.leaflet-control-container { position: absolute; right: -10px; width:0px; border: 0px; outline: 0;}`

Another thing I remembered recently is that clearing the browsing memory is really important with css... in case other beginners are reading this.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PT1x.png)

Comment: You can change most of the settings in leaflet.css.  Check in Developer Tools in your browser and select the box, this will show you what to edit.